# Chrome extension REST server

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to expose a REST endpoint (for access locally only ie via `http://localhost/api`) directly from my Chrome extension, without the messages/requests going through Google's services.

Is this possible?

EDIT: needs to be REST and not websocket.

Comment: FWIW you can do it in an app w/ `chrome.sockets.tcpServer`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.